# What is the '^' in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

## What does the '^' mean in the code below?

```
@implementation AppController

- (IBAction) loadComposition:(id)sender
{
    void (^handler)(NSInteger);

    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"qtz", nil]];

    handler = ^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            NSString *filePath = [[[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0] path];
            if (![qcView loadCompositionFromFile:filePath]) {
                NSLog(@"Could not load composition");
            }
        }
    };

    [panel beginSheetModalForWindow:qcWindow completionHandler:handler];
}
@end
```

===
I've searched and searched - is it some sort of particular reference to memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read up on it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html). It's a "Block object", which is basically a lambda form, and was introduced to support Snow Leopard's GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).

Answer (score 8):

Small aside: the '^' character (caret or circumflex character) has a different meaning when used as a binary operator:

```
a ^ b
```

means a XOR b. XOR (aka exclusive OR) is a binary arithmetic operation where the the result has a 1 in any bit position where either a or b had a 1 but not both.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [block](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/cocoa/introblocksgcd.html) (a.k.a. closure), an  extension of C created by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [block](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/), likely for use with [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch).