# what is meant by the objects starting with ^ in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caret in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c)

I recently came across some line of code and found out that it has `^` sign in front of an object like this one:

```
typedef void (^AnimatedViewBlock)(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CFTimeInterval totalTime, CFTimeInterval deltaTime);
@interface AnimatedView : UIView
```

Can anyone explain it with simple example about the same.

Comment: This question has been asked before... Check this:

[Caret in objective-C][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912023/caret-in-objective-c

Comment: See [here][1]. The first answer links to the iOS Developer Library. :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736261/what-is-the-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

It denotes a block object.

Read Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is so called **block**.

Objective-C kind of closure.

[Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

The symbol you are referring to denotes the start of a block in objective-c. They are primarily used in Grand Central Dispatch in ios but you can use them elsewhere as well.

As John Muchow [writes](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/introduction-to-blocks-in-objective-c-part-1.html):

> A block is really nothing more than a chunk of code. What makes them
>   unique is that a block can be executed inline as well as passed as an
>   argument into a method/function. Blocks can also be assigned to a
>   variable and called as you would a C function.

Comment: thanks for replying...i have gone through the Apple docs,though they have a nice explanation regarding this but still i am confused why we need blocks and as they are similar to functions then under what circumstances they will be used.

Comment: If you're going to copy the words of someone else, be sure to properly cite and quote them. Otherwise, you're committing plagiarism.

Comment: ok ... I read it on a site.. iphonedevelopertips.com

Comment: @AjeetPratapMaurya do some reading on [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)) to grasp some idea on what distinguishes them.