# Does Objective-C have closure while C does not?

Tags: objective-c, c, closures

I have heard that C doesn't have closure, and today I saw the use of closure in Objective-C.  Is closure supported in Objective-C and not in C?

**Update: thanks for all the answers.**  I found this guide on the web on blocks as well: http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the '^' in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736261/what-is-the-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple added the `^` operator to add closure support. It is not tied to Objective-C however, and can be used in C and C++ as well, as long as you compile the project with Apple's brach of GCC or LLVM. This new feature is called [blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29).

Comment: C standard doesn't have it tho.

Answer (score 0):

C has closures in the form of application-defined structures that contain both a function pointer and data pointer. The problem is just that many/most interfaces that take a callback pointer (like `qsort`) accept only the function pointer and not a corresponding data pointer, making it impossible to pass closures to them.

By the way, it's theoretically possible to add closure support at the library level without assistance from the compiler, i.e. create a library that would return a function pointer to a closure. However, the library code would be rather implementation/machine-dependent. It would need to allocate space for executable code and generate code to pass a fixed pointer value (saved as part of the closure object) along with other arguments to the function.